# How do I untab line (-1 tab)?

Tags: python, tabs

I am looking for a sign that can untab a line:

- `\t` - tabs a line
- `\n` - new line

How do I untab a line (-1 tab)? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: That doesn't really make sense, you just have one fewer `\t`s.

Comment: What do you mean by "untab"? Is this an X - Y question? What is your actually need?

Comment: Do you mean Shift + Tab which is the hotkey for some editor to decrease indent?

Comment: Or a `\x7f` which represents a delete?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such special character to "untab" a line. If you want to modify a string and remove only one tab, you can do so with `str.replace`:

```
mystring = mystring.replace('\t', '', 1)
```